# SKDownload not working in sandbox

Tags: ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit, iap-hosted-content

I'm trying to download content for an IAP, but it fails after a few calls to "`paymentQueue:updatedDownloads:`" method. The first two calls to this method show that the download is in the `SKDownloadStateActive` state with a progress of 0%. The third call has the download in the active state again, but this time with the download at 75%. The fourth call shows the download is in the `SKDownloadStateFailed` with an error of "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. I'm not calling "`finishTransaction:`" at any point in between. Only from the "`failed`" and "`finished`" states. Has anyone had a similar problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080791/ios-downloading-from-apple-server-after-inapp-purchase)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this on my iPad and it worked. I guess you can't test IAP hosted content from within the simulator.