# In app Purchase Apple hosted content - How to load nib from downloaded pkg file

Tags: iphone, ios6, in-app-purchase, nib, iap-hosted-content

I have following file structure in my hosted content, after extracting every possible archive in the way.

[image]

My hosted content was originally a pkg file which was uploaded to Apple, and after extracting it converts to the above structure. My in-app content is contained within the .nib file shown.

I have never worked with nib files before. But I have an idea that it is like storyboards in current XCode versions. However when I directly import the above nib file into xcode 4.5, I just see a plain white symbol, no controls or any meaningful app data. If I rename it to xib, I get to see some text with some jumbled characters, starting with text 'NIBArchive'.

My questions:

1 - How do I see if it is meaningful xib. Am I making any mistake? (It's the one originally submitted by someone else who is no longer around, so I have to ask)

2 - How can I download this pkg from Apple server (yes, I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994550/how-to-download-in-app-hosted-content/13226429#comment21024162_13226429) already but it doesn't refer to a pkg or xib file) and unzip / extract it to see above file structure.

3 - If I am successful in above two steps, how do I load this xib at runtime and make features available to the user.

I know 2 & 3 is too much to ask but even Apple forums do not have much to offer as far as Apple hosted content is concerned.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.