# RMStore / Storekit - Accessing the file automatically downloaded from Apple Hosted Content

Tags: download, storekit, rmstore

When using RMStore, does anyone know how I access the automatically downloaded Apple hosted content.

I can see that it is on the Library/Cache/somekindoffile.zip/ But how exactly can I call that content within the code.  Within storeDownloadFinished I can capture the location using [download.contentURL path].

I am hoping this is a bit of dumb question, but I can’t see anything in the docs, source code or find a way to launch or link to the file once downloading content automatically ends.

I'm sure it's obvious and I'm being a little simple - it's just causing me to rip out what little hair I have left.

Help on this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'somekindoffile.zip' is actually a folder, so there is no unzipping to be done. This threw me off for a while.

This post was very helpful to me for solving the issue of copying files from the cache to my library. [How to download In-App hosted content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994550/how-to-download-in-app-hosted-content)

In my library folder I created folders for each productIdentifier for the non-consumable downloads. I also added an MBProgressHUD determinate spinner (main thread) because the copying took a little bit and I didn't want a locked-up screen.